# Iteration in Dictionary

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, hashtable, enumeration

I have a dictionary i have to check a condition till last element of dictionary.I have used method movenext but it is throwing exception.What i wanted to do is when element in array B comes.Compare  each element with that in A till last element which is greater than B.Then remove that key value pair for which condition satisfies.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WellPuzzle
{

    class Solution
    {
        public void falling_disks(int[] A, int[] B)
        {

           Dictionary<int, int> d1 = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            List<KeyValuePair<int, bool>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, bool>>();

            var enum1 = d1.GetEnumerator();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= A.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                //h1.Add(count++,A[i]);
                d1.Add(count++, A[i]);
            }

            foreach (int ele in B)
            {

                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> item in d1)
                {
                    var pair = item.Value;

                    if (ele <=pair && (enum1.MoveNext()!=null))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (ele <= pair && (enum1.MoveNext() == null))
                    {

                        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, bool>(pair, true));
                        d1.Remove(pair);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //add key of current pair as filled in second hashtable
                        //remove element from first hashtable
                        //iterate till last
                        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, bool>(pair, true));
                        d1.Remove(pair);
                    }
}
}
}
}







    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] A = new int[] { 5, 6, 4, 3, 6, 2, 3 };
            int[] B = new int[] { 2 };
            Solution s1 = new Solution();
            s1.falling_disks(A, B);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What Exception it is throwing?

Comment: @Anonymiser: I see you're "using" System.Linq.  Surely there's already method there that can get you the results you need.  I'm having difficulty though understanding the exact results you want.  Can you present an input (`A` and `B` I presume) and output you're looking for?

Comment: @syedmohsin, obviously "collection modified while iterating" - as expected. Now since the question is missing it is unclear if Anonymiser wants this exception or need to do something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify an Enumeration while iterating over it. As in,

```
foreach(var item in someList)
{
   if (someCondition)
      someList.remove(item); // At run time you will get an exception saying that the collection was modified
}
```

In these situations you usually store the ids of the things that u need to remove then remove them by iterating over the new collection,

```
var itemsToRemove = new List<int>();
foreach(var item in someList)
{
   if (someCondition)
      itemsToRemove.Add(item.Id);
}

foreach(var id in itemsToRemove)
{
   var item = someList.First(l => l.Id = id)
   someList.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: but @bassam....while iterating i wanted to know whether i have reached last element of dictionary on a particular condition.Can some one please explain movenext method for dictionary?...or whether is there a way to reach last  element in dictionary that satisfies a condition